# Cannot append Data with panas.append function

Tags: python, pandas

following code is not running, I have no guess why.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Interval', 'Weight'])
intersection = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
weight = 0.85
df.append({'Intersection':intersection,'Weight':weight}, ignore_index=True)

print(df)
```

Allways I get just following result:

Empty DataFrame

Columns: [Interval, Weight]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Interval', 'Weight'])
intersection = np.array(range(1, 6))
weight = 0.85

# the initial dataframe is empty with two columns

# add or update columns with 
df['Intersection'] =  intersection
df['Weight'] = weight

# output
  Interval  Weight  Intersection
0      NaN    0.85             1
1      NaN    0.85             2
2      NaN    0.85             3
3      NaN    0.85             4
4      NaN    0.85             5
```

- Using [`df.append`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html)

  - **Returns** a new DataFrame that must be assigned to a variable.
- This will add the `Intersection` array as a single row.
- Use [`pandas.DataFrame.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html#pandas-dataframe-explode) to transform each element of a list to a row, replicating index values.

```py
df = df.append({'Intersection': intersection, 'Weight': weight}, ignore_index=True)

# result 
   Interval  Weight     Intersection
0       NaN    0.85  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

# if you want separate rows, use .explode
df = df.explode('Intersection')

# result
   Interval  Weight Intersection
0       NaN    0.85            1
0       NaN    0.85            2
0       NaN    0.85            3
0       NaN    0.85            4
0       NaN    0.85            5
```

- With `.append`, if you want separate rows, as shown in the docs.

```py
for i in intersection:
    df = df.append({'Intersection': i, 'Weight': weight}, ignore_index=True)

# result
   Interval  Weight  Intersection
0       NaN    0.85           1.0
1       NaN    0.85           2.0
2       NaN    0.85           3.0
3       NaN    0.85           4.0
4       NaN    0.85           5.0
```